# Adding fields transparently to all types

Tags: hibernate-search

Is there any integration point allowing to add a meta-field on all indexed documents transparently, right before they are indexed, similarly to `_hibernate_class`?
Currently using Hibernate 5.11

Answer (score 0):

As discussed over the chat, the only option in Search 5 is to use the [programmatic mapping API](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#hsearch-mapping-programmaticapi) to add a [class bridge](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.11/reference/en-US/html_single/#_classbridge) to every single indexed entity type.

In Search 6, you can use the [new programmatic mapping API](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-programmatic-mapping) to add a [type bridge](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-bridge-typebridge) to the `Object` type, and it will be applied to every type. It will also be applied to embedded types, though, so that may not be what you're after.